# How to display string which contains django template variables?

Tags: python, django, string, django-templates

Let's say I have an string variable called *magic_string* which value is set to "This product name is *{{ product.name }}*" and it's avaible at django template. Is it ever possible to parse that variable to show me "This product name is Samsung GT-8500" instead (assuming that name of the product is "GT-8500" and variable *{{ product.name }}* is avaible at the same template) ?

I was trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work (honestly ? Im not surprised):

```
{{ magic_string|safe }}
```

Any ideas/suggestions about my problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write custom template tag and render that variable as a template.
For example look at how ["ssi" tag is written](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaulttags.py#L304).

On the other hand, can you render this string in your view? Anyway here is an untested version of that tag:

```
@register.tag
def render_string(parser, token):
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) != 2:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("...")
    return RenderStringNode(bits[1])


class RenderStringNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, varname):
        self.varname = varname

    def render(self, context):
        var = context.get(self.varname, "")
        return Template(var).render(context)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you ! Sorry for not upvoting, but I need some more reputation to do that :(

Comment: If you want to use attributes of context variables (e.g. `person.name`) chuck `from django.template.base import resolve_variable` in the top, then change the 2nd to last line to `var = resolve_variable(self.varname, context)`.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps I dont understand your question but what about,

```
from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template("This product name is {{ product.name }}")

>>> c = Context({"product.name": " Samsung GT-8500"})
>>> t.render(c)
```

Regards.

Comment: So we're even, coz I dont understand the answer :) But anyway thanks for sharing !